# tsconfig shortcut path configuration not working for imports and auto-import

Tags: angular, typescript, import, webstorm, tsconfig

I want to use shortcut paths and auto import within my Angular project but unfortunately my IDE can't find the corresponding module (I can use relative paths to import it though), when I import something from one lib or component to another one:

> TS2307: Cannot find module '@libs/types' or its corresponding type declarations.

I use WebStorm with Angular 14.

I tried to configure it in the `tsconfig.json` but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my configuration:

**tsconfig.json (root level)**

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@libs/search": [
        "./src/app/libs/search/src/lib"
      ],
      "@libs/member": [
        "./src/app/libs/member/src/lib"
      ],
      "@libs/types": [
        "./src/app/libs/types/src/lib"
      ]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

**failed import in the component under src/app/libs/member/src/lib/components/member-public/member-public.component.ts**

```js
import {User} from '@libs/types'; // TS2307: Cannot find module '@libs/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

**src/app/libs/types/src/public-api.ts**

```js
export * from './lib/user.types';
```

**configuration in angular.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "src/app",
  "projects": {
    "test": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "test:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "test:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "@libs/search": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "src/app/libs/search",
      "sourceRoot": "src/app/libs/search/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "src/app/libs/search/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/search/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/search/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/app/libs/search/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/search/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/app/libs/search/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "@libs/member": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "src/app/libs/member",
      "sourceRoot": "src/app/libs/member/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "src/app/libs/member/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/member/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/member/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/app/libs/member/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/member/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/app/libs/member/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "@libs/types": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "src/app/libs/types",
      "sourceRoot": "src/app/libs/types/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "src/app/libs/types/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/types/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/types/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/app/libs/types/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/app/libs/types/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/app/libs/types/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**project structure**

[image: project structure]

**libs structure**

[image: libs structure]

Does anyone have a clue or know what I am doing wrong? Any advice is appreciated very much.

Comment: Can you add one `*` at the end like `"@libs/search/*": [
        "./src/app/libs/search/src/lib/*"
      ]`.

Comment: hey thanks buddy, that did the trick! But now i am importing from the file directly like this:

import {SearchService} from '@libs/search/search.service';

but how is it possible to import from the public-api.ts?

Comment: Add the exported members to one index file, that is one thing you can chck

Comment: but they are already exported by the public-api.ts like so:
export * from './lib/user.types';


i would have thought i can access them now in another component like so:
import {User} from '@libs/types'